# Samba authentication fails

Tags: server, permissions, samba, file-sharing

I have been endlessly searching for what went wrong, and can't figure it out. There is a lot that I still don't understand about working with samba on Ubuntu, so if something looks noobish, I am sorry.

Before I updated my ubuntu server, sharing was acting normal and the teacher account was able to authenticate, when I updated though, it stopped working.

I'm using Ubuntu server:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily

and samba: Version 4.1.17-Ubuntu

When I try to map a network drive from a windows computer (windows 10 in this case, also used windows 7 with similar results), i get the following log results in **/var/logs/samba/log.(ip address of windows)** :

```
check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [teacher] -> [teacher] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER
[2016/01/06 14:00:51.944975,  3] ../source3/auth/auth_util.c:1593(do_map_to_guest_server_info)
  No such user teacher [HeritageFileServer] - using guest account
```

From the windows machine I am logging in as HeritageFileServer\teacher, i also tried HERITAGEFILESERVER\teacher, and just teacher, in the past, the first one worked just fine.

If I type sudo **pdbedit -L -v**, which as I understand, is supposed to list my samba users, I get this:

```
---------------
Unix username:        tech
NT username:          
Account Flags:        [U          ]
User SID:             S-1-5-21-3838925055-3536237277-778935331-1000
Forcing Primary Group to 'Domain Users' for tech
Primary Group SID:    S-1-5-21-3838925055-3536237277-778935331-513
Full Name:            Tech
Home Directory:       \\heritagefileserver\tech
HomeDir Drive:        
Logon Script:         
Profile Path:         \\heritagefileserver\tech\profile
Domain:               HERITAGEFILESERVER
Account desc:         
Workstations:         
Munged dial:          
Logon time:           0
Logoff time:          never
Kickoff time:         never
Password last set:    Wed, 06 Jan 2016 13:07:05 MST
Password can change:  Wed, 06 Jan 2016 13:07:05 MST
Password must change: never
Last bad password   : 0
Bad password count  : 0
Logon hours         : FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
---------------
Unix username:        teacher
NT username:          
Account Flags:        [U          ]
User SID:             S-1-5-21-3838925055-3536237277-778935331-1001
Forcing Primary Group to 'Domain Users' for teacher
Primary Group SID:    S-1-5-21-3838925055-3536237277-778935331-513
Full Name:            
Home Directory:       \\heritagefileserver\teacher
HomeDir Drive:        
Logon Script:         
Profile Path:         \\heritagefileserver\teacher\profile
Domain:               HERITAGEFILESERVER
Account desc:         
Workstations:         
Munged dial:          
Logon time:           0
Logoff time:          never
Kickoff time:         never
Password last set:    Mon, 04 Jan 2016 15:22:14 MST
Password can change:  Mon, 04 Jan 2016 15:22:14 MST
Password must change: never
Last bad password   : 0
Bad password count  : 0
Logon hours         : FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Obviously teacher exists, and the password is very simple, so I'm certain i'm not getting it wrong, I even reset the password to make sure by using smbpasswd.

I ended up setting the important folders to allow guest accounts so the teachers could access the drive, meanwhile I'm trying to get the log to show that it successfully authenticated. Here is my smb.conf file (I have share and Share as the original folders that are now open to guests, while Shared is my test folder that I am trying to get to work with authentication):

```
#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]

;workgroup = WORKGROUP

server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

dns proxy = no

#interfaces = eth0

log level = 3

log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

max log size = 1000

syslog = 0


####### Authentication #######

;server role = standalone server

security = user

guest account = nobody

map to guest = bad user

;usershare allow guests = yes

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

 [printers]
comment = All Printers
browseable = yes
path = /var/spool/samba
printable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = yes
create mask = 0700

[print$]
comment = Printer Drivers
path = /var/lib/samba/printers
browseable = yes
read only = yes
guest ok = yes

[share]
comment= Heritage File Server
path = /media/external/ServerBackup
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
create mask = 0755

[Share]
comment= Heritage File Server
path = /media/external/ServerBackup
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
create mask = 0755

[Shared]
comment= Heritage File Server
path = /media/external/ServerBackup
available = yes
valid users = teacher
browsable = yes
guest ok = no
read only = no
writable = yes
create mask = 0755

[web]
comment = Heritage Web Hosting
path = /var/www/html
browsable = yes
guest ok = no
read only = no
create mask = 0755

[homes]
comment = Home Directories
browsable = yes
read only = yes
```

Anybody know what is wrong?

Answer (score 13):

Open a terminal and try this:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a < username>
```

Here, < username> is your username. Now, you will be prompted to set and retype new password.

Then, restart the smb service:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Now, try to open the shared location the usual way. Type the username and the new password you have just set.

You should be able to log in now.

Comment: Wish I could test this. At a new job now so I guess I will never find out.

Comment: Yes, the post is from two years ago. I should have expected that :)

Comment: Fixed my problem, thank you.

Comment: You can upvote and/or mark this as the accepted answer if it has worked for you :)